# matching 2 dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have 2 dataframes in pandas like below
but 2 dataframes don't have same columns, only few columns are same.

```
df1
no  datas1 datas2 datas3 datas4
 0      a    b      a      a
 1      b    c      b      b
 2      d    b      c      a

df2
no  datas1 datas2 datas3  data4  data 5  data6
 0      c    a      a       a      a       b
 1      a    c      b       b      b       b
 2      a    b      c       b      c       c
```

I'd like to know how much it's matched for each same column based on "no" filed using pandas functions

the result are below

```
data3 is 100% match
data4 is 66% match

or

data3 is 3 matched
data4 is 2 matched
```

What's the best way to make like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this - first run `equals` method and if True then print that dataframes match, otherwise use `compare` method and then calculate the percentage of rows that matched between dfs:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 7]})

if df1.equals(df2):
    print('df1 matched df2')
else:
    comp = df1.compare(df2)
    match_perc = (df1.shape[0] - comp.shape[0]) / df1.shape[0]

print(f'{match_perc * 100: .4f} match')  # Out: 33.3333 match
```

You can simplify by just using compare and if the dataframes match perfectly then you print that they matched:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})


comp = df1.compare(df3)
match_perc = (df1.shape[0] - comp.shape[0]) / df1.shape[0]
if match_perc == 1:
    print('dfs matched')
else:
    print(f'{match_perc * 100: .4f} match')

# Out: dfs matched
```